# Ошибка в получении минимальной цены через array_reduce

Tags: php

В переменной $data

```
array(1000) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(7) "0.10467"...
```

Пытаюсь найти минимальную цену

```
$minPrice = array_reduce($data, function($p, $c) {
  return ((float) $p['price'] > (float) $c['price']) ? $c : $p;
});
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\server\domains\localhost\app\controllers\products.php on line 93
```

93 строка это где return

Comment: вам обязательно через reduce?

Comment: @splash58 нет, можно по другому

Comment: тогда вопрос, как всегда - это данные из БД? Почему сразу не получить оттуда?

Comment: данные получаю по API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно распоряжаетесь аргументами функции и возвращаемым значением.

До php 7.2 остается проблема установки начального значения, заведомо большего, чем все цены в массиве. Позже можно подставить PHP_FLOAT_MAX

```
echo $minPrice = array_reduce($data, function($c, $i) {
  return ($c > (float) $i['price']) ? (float) $i['price'] : $c;
}, PHP_FLOAT_MAX);
```